# Google Charts: How to get the percentage values of every slice in a pie chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I want to get the value of the percentages for every slice, at the moment I am able to get the name of the selected label but I would like to get the percentage value for every label. I couldn't find a method to do that, is this possible?

http://jsfiddle.net/oaobxych/4/

```
function selectHandler() {
          var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
          if (selectedItem) {
            var version = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
            alert('The user selected ' + version);
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you'll have to calculate it.

```
    var total = 0;
    for (var f = 0; f < data.getNumberOfRows(); f++){
        total += data.getValue(f, 1);
    }
      var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
      if (selectedItem) {
        var percentage = (data.getValue(selectedItem.row,1)*100/total).toFixed(1);
        var version = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
        alert('The user selected ' + version + ' a ' + percentage + '% of total');
      }
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oaobxych/7/

Comment: I spent too much time finding a single line (ie unreadable) way of getting the sum to not share: `var total = google.visualization.data.sum(data.getSortedRows(1).map(function(i) { return data.getValue(i,1); }))`

Comment: I was able to get this working with a combination of both comments. Thank you!